# Subprocess call with quoted arguments

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run the following command using subprocess module:

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/matlab -r "func_call('output', '/path/to/location/')"
```

Note that Matlab requires function calls to be in double quotes. The above command works find from bash command line. Here is what I have done in python

```
func = "func_call('output', '/path/to/loc/')"
cmd = "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/matlab "
options = "-r \"%s\"" % func
run_cmd = cmd + options
proc = subprocess.Popen(run_cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate()
```

I get following error:

```
('', '/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/matlab: eval: line 1738: syntax error near unexpected token `)\'\n/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/matlab: eval: line 1738: `exec  "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/gla64/MATLAB"  -r ""\'"func_call(\'"\'output\'," \'/path/to/loc/\')"\'\n/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/matlab: line 1738: warning: syntax errors in . or eval will cause future versions of the shell to abort as Posix requires\n')
```

I am assuming that it is the quotes that are messing the execution. Am I right? How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try `import shlex; shlex.split(run_cmd)` instead of the plain `str.split()`? However it's simply easier to create the command-line as a list from the beginning. In this way you have total control on the splitting.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is because of the `split` you have, that splits on all spaces including the spaces between quotes. Try this:

```
func = "func_call('output', '/path/to/loc/')"
cmd = "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/matlab"
run_cmd = [cmd, "-r", func]
proc = subprocess.Popen(run_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate()
```

Notice that I didn't put another set of quotes around func. Those quotes in a shell, ie bash, tell the shell that everything between them is a single argument, those quotes get parsed by the shell and not actually part of the argument. In python every string, after the first which is the command, is a single argument so you don't need to do anything special.

Comment: `proc.communicate()` might create giant strings in memory that you do not use. You could replace it with `out, err = proc.communicate()` to make it clear that the output is accumulated or use `subprocess.DEVNULL` analog instead of `subprocess.PIPE` to discard the output.